# Is it possible to add custom cases to moment.js 'time from now'

Tags: momentjs

Here are the 'time from now' cases and their corresponding output:
[image]

The output and the range can be changed, but I'm trying to do something a bit different.
Is it possible to add custom  keys, for example if it is less than 5 minutes than show 'Just now'. Or if it is more than 24 hours and the same week then output the day's name, etc.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this kind of output - Can you please show us your minimum attempts of code ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I looked through the documentation and I didn't find a way to add custom cases so there is no code to show... My question is if it is even possible and if so how to set custom cases, I'm not asking for some one to make them for me

Comment: Yes its possible! In the documentation you will see this [Relative Time](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/) - you need to customise it according to your needs :)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Thanks! But I have already seen this part and from what I could tell it allows to change the output for the given cases. What I'm trying to do is to create new cases, e.g. less when 5 minutes. The existing cases define until which threshold to count in a specific measurement which is not what I need